# When to use the looks good on low quality reviews?

Tags: support

The low quality review options have me confused quiet often.

When exactly should the "looks good" option be used? When it "looks good" and issent off low quality. Or "looks good" the appropriate actions aka down vote/comments have been made?

Comment: "Looks Good" effectively means "not bad enough to close/delete" - it doesn't necessarily mean that you think the post is actually _good_, just that it _isn't awful_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally believe the options could be better worded.

"Looks Good" basically means you've reviewed the post and have taken all the actions that you can do. "Skip" essentially means "I don't know what do to here, so I'll just leave this in queue for another reviewer sort out."

As for what the "Looks Good" button actually does, see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143469/in-the-new-review-beta-what-does-the-looks-good-button-actually-do). As for how they came about, take a look at [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147867).

Comment: That answers it, thank you ^^